# Push Segue triggers a Modal Segue that leads to VC with no navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

My structure is:

ViewController A [-> (modal)] Navigation Controller -> ViewController B [-> (push)] ViewController C

In other words: VC A has a button you push to do a modal segue to VC B (which happens to be embedded in a Navigation Controller).  
Then in VC B, you click on a table view cell and this triggers a push segue to VC C.  All segues were made on the storyboard and identifiers were appropriately named.

The Issue is: When you click on the table view cell that transitions from VC B to VC C, the transition does correctly go to VC C, but it animates like a modal segue and VC C does not have a navigation bar (even when I specifically set `navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false`).  Thus, there is no back button.

For debugging purposes, I embedded VC A in a nav controller and had a button from there segue to a new VC with the push segue and the same thing happened (that thing being that the transition did not spawn the nav bar). Any ideas to solve this issue?

EDIT: Basic idea of the VC setup.  Note that segue from VC A to VC B is done in code.

[image: VC Setup]

Comment: Can you try embedding VC C in a navigation controller as well then segue to that

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion!  I just tried that, but it didn't work.  I also tried deleting and setting the segue up again after embedding VC C in a nav controller, but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: No problem my friend. When you set up the new segue did you segue to the nav controller or to VC C directly?

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly, if you can upload your image of storyboard i think it is better than to solve this

Comment: @ACerts I set it up both ways and both didn't work.  I assume it's supposed to be to the nav though, right?

Comment: @seyha Added images for reference

Comment: Yes segue to the nav. I would add a screenshot of your storyboards to your post if possible. Might help to catch something a little easier

Comment: @ACerts Thanks! And just did that

Comment: Just saw, thanks. Looking at the image, does VC A bave a segue to the nav controller of VC B?

Comment: @ACerts Thanks so much, you caught the error!  I had coded the segue to VC B before embedding VC B in the navigation controller.  Thus, I was segueing to VC B rather than its navigation controller.  If you add that as an answer I'll select it.  Either way thanks for the help!!

Comment: Just added the answer now. I am glad we figured it out! Have a great night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this you need to connect the modal segue from VC A to VC B’s Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0):

In VC A you should present navigation controller of VC B. 
And then in VC B (not its navigation controller) you should connect segue to VC C directly no need to embed navigation controller for VC C. 
you will get back button after you connected.